# extjs Save component view state before removing it from parent component

Tags: view, state, extjs5

Let me explain the my scenario. I am using ExtJS5. I have got a view component (let us name is viewOne) contain two combo boxes, button search and some action button, on click of search button the grid is populated.  This viewOne is in a parent view component (viewParent). I need to load a second view (viewTwo) on selecting some grid row and clicking some action button a new view is loaded (viewTwo) in the parentView. When I come back from viewTwo to viewOne I need old values of combo boxes to re perform the search.

Currently I am storing the values of combo boxes in a store and set then when the after view render and call search. We have discarded card layout for this implementation.

I wanted to know how this can be done via Ext.state , I cannot find any example on the same that is close solution to my problem. Any other way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

State seems reasonable for that. First of all you must set `StateProvider` (by calling `Ext.state.Manager.setProvider`) to instance of class which extends `Ext.state.Provider`.
Then state should work for you. Only thing that you must remember is to set `stateful` property to `true` and set `stateId` of the component.

Usually you don't need to save state by yourself. All built-in stateful components have defined state events. When such state event occur (eg. `expand` on panel) then state is saved automatically. You can customize state events by calling `addStateEvents` in initComponent.

To provide custom component state you should override `applyState` and `getState` methods. When you combine it with `addStateEvents` you have all what you need.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/48jw81da/16/